# Transparent video in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video, transparent, alpha

Do you have an idea how to add transparent video (with alpha channel) to Flutter?

I had some luck with https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vap  but it doesn't work on Web, only Android and iOS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So the question is: Do you have an idea how to add transparent video (with alpha channel) to Flutter for Web?